# LastModifiedDateTime spontaneously changed at 1-2 seconds after uploading new file to OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

My application uploads new file version or creates new file in OneDrive via Microsoft Graph C# SDK and traks changes in it while application is runing. I've noticed that after 1-2 seconds LastModifiedDateTime of new file has been changed and it's critical for me because i know that neither my app or other users\clients have changed new file metadata or content. Also i've noticed that cTag has not been changed while eTag was changed with LastModifiedDateTime.
Who updates new file metadata in OneDrive after file uploading? And how rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use fileSystemInfo.lastModifiedDateTime ( NOT lastModifiedDateTime).

(sorry I'm japanese. probably you can read english page.)

https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/driveitem?view=odsp-graph-online

It is as follows.

```
JSON {
  lastModifiedDateTime,       # Date and time the item was last modified. Read-only.
  fileSystemInfo: {
    createdDateTime,
    lastAccessedDateTime,
    lastModifiedDateTime      # The UTC date and time the file was last modified on a client.
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but `fileSystemInfo.lastModifiedDateTime` is not good solution. It's filling on client side so it could be problem if client and server clocks are not synced.